# How to give a parameter to iframe youtube video

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

i'd like to update a youtube iframe by some datas which are store on firebase. What is the good syntax ? My parameter is call "concert.youtube" Here is my code :

```
<button onclick="myFunction();return false;">Click me</button>
<div id="video"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("video").innerHTML = "<div id='player'></div>";


            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        }

        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: "concert.youtube",
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }
      {
         event.target.playVideo();
        }

        var done = false;
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                //setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                done = true;
            }
        }
        function stopVideo() {
            player.stopVideo();
        }
```

Thanks, for your help

Comment: I think what you want to do is change `player = new YT.Player('player'` to `player = new YT.Player('video'`  as the first parameter represent the id of the element you want to put the video.

Comment: doesn't change anything. If I print my "concert.youtube" the id of the video is well printed. I'm lost :/